# Parse a datetime from a string in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string variable like the following:

```
./file_timestamp_2020_02_11_09_00_19
```

I would like to extract the datetime from this string and set it as a variable in the following format:

```
2020-02-11T09:00:19
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
filename=$"./file_timestamp_2020_02_11_09_00_19"
output=$($filename | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}_[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2}')
datetime=$($output +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$filename'
```

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: right, assuming GNU date(1).

Comment: @Alex Scott , you're almost there `echo "$filename" | grep -Eo '([[:digit:]]{4}_[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2})'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```sh
#!/bin/bash

convert () {
  IFS=_
  echo "$1" | while read -a T; do
    echo "${T[2]}-${T[3]}-${T[4]}T${T[5]}:${T[6]}:${T[7]}"
  done
}

converted=$(convert "./file_timestamp_2020_02_11_09_00_19")

echo $converted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following GNU sed command :

```
 sed -E 's/.*([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2}).*/\1-\2-\3T\4:\5:\6/'
```

[Try it here](https://ideone.com/JEj0sp).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file ends in the format you provided, i.e. `####_##_##_##_##_##` this should work from a quick test. Though it ain't pretty it's a simple solution.

```
originalString="file_timestamp_2020_02_11_09_00_19"
newString="${originalString:(-19)}"
newString=$( echo "${newString}" | sed 's/_/-/g' )
newString=$( echo "${newString}" | sed 's/-/T/3' )
newString=$( echo "${newString}" | sed 's/-/:/3g' )
```

Edit: [This site](https://shellmagic.xyz/#variable-manipulation) has a good collection on variable/string manipulation methods btw!

Answer (score 0):

Tested on dash,sh,ksh,ash,zsh and of course bash, I know not so pretty...

```
var=./file_timestamp_2020_02_11_09_00_19 
echo "$var" | { IFS=_ read -r _ _ var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 ; echo "$var3-${var4}-${var5}T${var6}:${var7}:$var8"; }
```

output

```
2020-02-11T09:00:19
```

or bash only using `-a` option of read, arrays and a bash specific P.E.

```
echo "$var" | { while IFS=_ read  -ra  var; do echo "${var[@]:2:1}-${var[@]:3:1}-${var[@]:4:1}T${var[@]:5:1}:${var[@]:6:1}:${var[@]:(-1)}"; done; }
```

Comment: `"${var[@]:2:1}"` is really easier written as `"${var[2]}"`, no?

Comment: whatever is easier.